# How is Budan espresso machine?

Tags: espresso-machine

I am a home brewer looking for a good manual espresso machine. I was quite inclined to a Breville one, but it exceeds my budget.

That's when I came upon a [Budan espresso machine](https://somethingsbrewing.in/products/budan-espresso-machine?utm_source=null&utm_medium=null&utm_campaign=null). The design and build of this machine looks great, and it has a better steam wand than my previous Delonghi C3240 (which had a plastic one).

I want to get reviews from the people who have used Budan before. Any other suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I understand your motivation. Your question straddles the fine line between ok (read as “describe the characteristics you noticed”) and opinion-based (read as “do you like it, is it a good machine”). The latter would be a type of question that is off topic here, so as a moderator I waited to see which direction potential answers would lean towards. It seems that our community has no significant experience with the the machine.